# The resource is not on the build path of a Java project

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I am building my projects with the help of maven.I have installed m2e plugin in eclipse.However, each time it gives me this message:

The resource is not on the build path of a Java project.

Comment: Could you post more details? It's hard to tell what's going on with the lack of information given.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what i did

right click on project Properties ==> project facets-> check the option for Java and press ok.

if no facets exits after you click on project facets then add one and check java option and you should be fine